Ink working in unity editor but not in build
I recently decided to change my dialogue system for my game and started searching for new one on youtube, I found this really good tutorial series which uses Ink and Unity, Ink seemed interesting so I made the decision to use it in my project. It all worked fine in the editor but once I built my project the dialogue system broke, it would type the first letter of the text and just stop.
I have tried searching online but I found nothing of use to me, I also tried reading Unity's build log and I found one error

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at DialogueManager+"<DisplayLine>d__40.MoveNext () [0x0007f] in <7eb5079f1f1f40d890d737872046460b>:0
at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00026] in <e036a72b7a734c938bd0e3bb10424e1b>:0

It seems to me like the Coroutine which I am using is null, but why would it be null only in build and not in the editor, I think when I try to yield return null that is when it breaks since it does type the first letter.
Here is the code fore the DisplayLine Coroutine:
private IEnumerator DisplayLine(string line)
{
    dialogueText.text = line;
    dialogueText.maxVisibleCharacters = 0;

    continueIcon.SetActive(false);
    HideChoices();

    //submitSkip = false;
    canContinueToNextLine = false;
    isAddingRichTextTag = false;

    StartCoroutine(CanSkip());

    foreach (char letter in line.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (canSkip && input.Continue)
        {
            //submitSkip = true;
            dialogueText.maxVisibleCharacters = line.Length;
            break;
        }

        if (letter == '<' || isAddingRichTextTag)
        {
            isAddingRichTextTag = true;
            if (letter == '>')
                isAddingRichTextTag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            AudioManager.instance.PlayOneShot(FMODEvents.instance.characterWriteSfx, transform.position);
            //dialogueText.text += letter;
            dialogueText.maxVisibleCharacters++;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    continueIcon.SetActive(true);
    DisplayChoices();

    canContinueToNextLine = true;
}

And here is the code where the DisplayLine is being called:
private void ContinueStory()
{
    if (currentStory.canContinue)
    {
        if (displayLineCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(displayLineCoroutine);
        }
        string nextLine = currentStory.Continue();

        if (nextLine.Equals("") && !currentStory.canContinue)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ExitDialogueMode());
        }
        else
        {
            displayLineCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DisplayLine(nextLine));
            HandleTags(currentStory.currentTags);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(ExitDialogueMode());
    }
}

If needed I can show all of the code, I just thought that it would be too much since it has close to 300 lines of code.
Thanks in advance.

OK so it doesn't crash in the Editor, but does it work as expected? Also, I highly doubt a coroutine is null :) Are you making the build using IL2CPP or Mono?

Everything works as excpected in the editor, I haven't had any issues which is why I am so confused about this. Also I am using Mono

What has 300 lines of code? DialogueManager? Also show CanSkip() and ExitDialogueMode please. Please give a bit more details about this crash. When does it happen, do you need to click anything or is it just during the conversations? Is it at the same spot all the time or different texts? How easy is it to reproduce?

Something is null inside of DisplayLine.  Add logs for anything that can be null in the coroutine.  After experiencing the issue in build, check those logs for which object is null and backtrack the issue from there.

@hijinxbassist my sentiments exactly. My money is on AudioManager.instance.PlayOneShot(FMODEvents.instance.characterWriteSfx, transform.position);. Possibly some asset that is not included or a singleton that is not instantiated or an issue with importing FMOD like a missing DLL.

@Marko Can you please show us the contents of the plugins directory in the Editor and the data directory of the build?

I fixed it, for some reason the input.continue was null but only in the in the second cycle of foreach, I don't understand how but I just changed from getting in in Awake to giving it [SerializeField] and assigning it in the inspector.
What is also weird is that when I debbuged it, it wasn't null but it would still freeze.
Thanks for help.

What input.continue? We don't see it in the code you showed us.

It is the in the first IF statement of the DisplayLine coroutine.

OK, that makes sense. Glad you fixed it! GL with the project!
